# Cannot use UISwitch in a Custom Cell to move to new Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to use the change event on a UISwitch to move from the current ViewController to a new one. My UISwitch is registered in my CustomView for the Custom Cell in my UITableView. The action is registered an calls a class in my View Controller as below

```
import UIKit

public class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {  
    @IBOutlet weak var operatedSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func operatedSwitchChange() {
        updateValveOps.valveUpdate()
    }
```

When it gets to my class in my ViewController it calls a method in the main class which should move to my new ViewController as below

```
import UIKit

class updateValveOps {
    class func valveUpdate() {
        let valveOps = ValveOperationsController()
        valveOps.ValveOpsUpdate()
    }
}

class ValveOperationsController: UIViewController {
.
.
func ValveOpsUpdate() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ValveOpsToUpdateSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

However, this causes a Sigabrt error. I've also tried pushing from the current view to the new View Controller but then for some reason it returns back to the calling View Controller! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help a lot if you follow naming conventions e.g. Starting calss name with Capital letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to get this working by using Protocol. First I added a Protocol to my ValveOperationsController and referenced it as below

```
protocol CustomCellDelegator {
    func callSegueFromCell()
}

class ValveOperationsController: UIViewController, CustomCellDelegator {
```

Then I added a delegate to my cell in cellForRowInIndexPath

```
    cell.delegate = self
```

Then I added the method called in my Protocol in to my ViewController

```
func callSegueFromCell() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ValveOpsToUpdateSegue", sender: nil )
}
```

Then going to my CustomTableViewCell I added my delegate

```
var delegate:CustomCellDelegator!
```

Then in the event called when the Switch changes I added the call to my Protocol

```
if(self.delegate != nil){ //Just to be safe.
        self.delegate.callSegueFromCell()
}
```

When the event is called when the switch changes it calls the Protocol which passes it to my method and the Segue operates successfully

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your   `@IBAction func operatedSwitchChange() { .. }`

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.visibleViewController()?.performSegueWithIdentifier("ValveOpsToUpdateSegue", sender: nil)
```

And add this extension to your project (copy-paste this into new swift file):

```
public extension UIWindow {

    func visibleViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let rootViewController: UIViewController = self.rootViewController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(rootViewController)
        }
        return nil
    }

    class func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc:UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        if vc == nil {
            return nil
        }

        if let navigationController = vc as? UINavigationController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom( navigationController.visibleViewController)
        } else if let tabBarController = vc as? UITabBarController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tabBarController.selectedViewController)
        } else {
            if let presentedViewController = vc?.presentedViewController {
                return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(presentedViewController.presentedViewController)
            } else {
                return vc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bacon, there seemed to be a syntax error as visibleViewController did not exist. I replaced it with inputViewController but it returned a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIOn error.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the code ran without any problems but still ended up back at the calling view with UISwitch. The first line it hits is 5 and then 5 again and finally 3, which means vc is nil on the last pass.